# Sum a column from a table and subtract it to a summed column in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables TblInventory and TblWithdrawal. TblInventory has productID as well as TblWithdrawal.

Grouping by ProductID, how do I SUM the Quantity in TblInventory and `SUM` the Quantity in TblWithdrawal and then `SUBTRACT` it to one another so I can get the remaining or difference in Quantity of each ProductID?

This is what I came up with, but when I run the query, it asks me to input a parameter which is wrong because I want it to automatically go through the table and do the operations on each ProductID.

```
SELECT TblInventory.ProductID,
       SUM(TblInventroy.Quantity) - SUM(TblWithdrawals.Quantity) As [Remaining]
FROM TblInventory
  LEFT JOIN TblWithdrawals ON TblInventory.ProductID = TblWithdrawals.ProductID 
WHERE TblInventory.ProductID = TblWithdrawals.ProductID
GROUP BY TblInventory.ProductID
```

Thank you. I really need to solve this!

Comment: What parameter does it ask for? Probably TblInventroy which you've misspelt.

Comment: Don't use WHERE clause for a join condition, move that one too to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (As it is now, it executes as a regular inner join...)

Answer (score 0):

Don't user WHERE clause. And use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Use Sub queries,First write group sqls then join it as you want. Look following sql. 
SELECT invent.ProductID, invent.invQty- withdrawl.withdrQty as Remaining 
FROM  ( SELECT ProductID,SUM(Quantity) as invQty 
                   FROM TblInventory ) as invent 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (  SELECT ProductID,SUM(Quantity) as withdrQty 
                    FROM  TblWithdrawals )  as withdrawl 
        ON invQty.ProductID=withdrawl.ProductID

Try This Best wishes

Comment: I think this one is right. But as soon as I use it, I get a syntax error in JOIN operation. This is my code: SELECT invent.ProductID, invent.invQty - withdrawal.withdrawQty AS Remaining
FROM (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS invQty
FROM TblInventory) AS invent
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS withdrawQty
FROM TblWithdrawals) AS withdrawal
ON invQty.ProductID = withdrawal.ProductID

Comment: BOSS it should be LEFT OUTER JOIN. you wrote LEFT JOIN